# MariaDB default float can't contain decimal places

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, heidisql

I am learning about MariaDBs column types and noticed this on my MariaDB db (latest dockerized 10.3.13), connected via HeidiSQL 10.

I can't set the default value for my FLOAT column to a value that contains decimal places:

[image]

**After hitting save the default value is just 42**. This also happens when performing the ALTER / CREATE TABLE query manually. (In the screenshot the column type is `FLOAT` but I also tested with `FLOAT(10,2)`.)

**Edit**: When creating the table with this SQL statement, new rows will have the default value 42 instead of 42.11:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test2 (
    `float` FLOAT(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '42.11'
)
```

Why?

Comment: Perhaps you can try: ALTER TABLE `table`  ADD COLUMN `column` FLOAT(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '42.11'

Comment: locale issue? Decimal comma?

Comment: I don't think it is a locale issue. Using '.' as the decimal place is working if I insert rows and using ',' will throw an error.

Comment: @FabianTe  Set the decimal length to something like 10,2 as it may otherwise default to 0.

Comment: @JimCastro Good idea. I just tested this with FLOAT(10,2) but the default value is still only 42.

Comment: @FabianTe  I'm running HeidiSQL on Linux Mint using WINE and it works for me so we get back to is it a locale issue?   Should you enter the length as 10.2 and the default value as 42,11  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just reported that to HeidiSQL, This is only a display bug on HeidiSQL: https://github.com/HeidiSQL/HeidiSQL/issues/593

You can execute "SHOW CREATE TABLE test2" or insert data into test2, this will show you that default value is not truncated.

Comment: Cool, thank you for verifying and creating the issue!